# Does ios has has any control similar to tabview of chrome or safari in iPad?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to find the tab view for ios. Not the TabView in Apple documentation, but a tab view like

[image]

So basically a control that consists of multiple tabs, each tab contains a page. And you can add/remove tabs, also rearrange tabs using drag and drop.

But I can't find it on apple official documentation. I want to know if there is anything available in iOS, either through a first-party API or third-party library.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this, most likely because web browser styled tabs would not be considered good UI for a screen size that small. Not even safari on iOS uses tabs like this.

Comment: But iOS share between iPhone and iPad. I agree with you that for the size of phone, there is no need for this style UI. However, it would be necessary for the size of the iPad. And the Safari on the iPad does this kind of UI. Thus, I am wondering if there is anything similar already exists so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Valid point... I did a little more research and was able to find this: https://iosexample.com/a-replacement-for-uitabviewcontroller-which-mimics-safari-tabs-on-ios/ Which may be of use to you

Comment: No, there is no such default control in iOS like this and you need to write your own custom control.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you're looking for a `UISegementController`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but according to my understanding, Segmented Controls is also static, similar to Tab View. (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/selectors/segmented-controls/)

Comment: I believe that is a design guideline; not necessarily an implementation limitation. I believe a `UIViewController` (or even a `UITableViewController`) would accept a `UISegmentController` in their `Views` collection.